# Getting function key press on NSSearchField without subclassing

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsevent, nssearchfield

I have a simple application which has an `NSSearchField` and I want to know if the user presses, for example, an arrow key. I don't want to subclass, because I want to modify the values of the IBOutlets in my aplication, and I can't do that in a subclass.

EDIT

The `keyUp:` method that I override in my `NSSearchField` subclass is:

```
-(void)keyUp:(NSEvent*)event
{
    if ([event keyCode]==36){
    customers* c= [[customers alloc] init];//customers is the class where i have my IBOulets and my methods
    [[self window] selectKeyViewFollowingView:self];// change the first responder
    [c searcht:[self stringValue]];//here i want to call a method to make a query and change the stringValues of some IBOulets
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assign your controller as the delegate of your searchfield and implement the method:

```
- (BOOL)control:(NSControl *)control textView:(NSTextView *)textView doCommandBySelector:(SEL)command
```

You should then be able to receive simple NSResponder selectors such as moveDown:, moveUp:, moveLeft:, moveRight: which correspond to the arrow keys.

Answer (score 2):

NSSearchField inherits from NSControl which has the delegate method you are looking for.

```
- (void)controlTextDidChange:(NSNotification *)aNotification
```

Set the NSSearchField as your delegate and implement this method. Might want to run a check to make sure it's your NSSearchField that's started editing. Maybe you could use FirstResponder. Something like:

```
- (void)controlTextDidChange:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    If (mySearchField.isFirstResponder) {
        //throwdown
    }
}
```

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSControl

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to get the `NSEvent`s that have already been handed to a view whose code you don't have. If you want to change the key-handling behavior of a view or control, you have to subclass. You might be able to insert another object *before* the search field in the responder chain, get the event, do whatever you want, and then act like you didn't handle it and pass it on to the field...just a wild thought from the top of my head.

**UPDATE** in reply to your `keyUp:` code:

Okay, the problem is becoming clear. When you create that new `customer`* object in code, you also have to hook up its connections in code. They're not connected for you. You don't actually use `IBOutlets` for this, just regular old ivars. `IBOutlets` are only there so that you can connect objects in the graphical interface of Interface Builder. I don't know exactly what you're trying to do in `searcht:`, but just as an example, if you wanted to change the contents of a text field:

```
- (void)searcht:(NSString *)theString {

    // Do some stuff with the string

    [myTextField setStringValue:someResultString];

}
```

Where customer.h looks something like:

```
@interface customer : NSObject {
    IBOutlet NSTextField * myTextField;
}
```

This will do nothing, including give no warning, because `myTextField` is `nil`. You can call methods on `nil` all day long and nothing will happen. What you need to do is give the `customer` object a pointer to the text field; this should not be an `IBOutlet`. You could do this in an `init...` method, or just by setting it directly (note that this means that the search field will have to have a connection to the text field in order to pass it on to the `Customer`, which may or may not be desirable):

```
@interface Customer : NSObject {
    NSTextField * myTextField;
}

@property NSTextField * myTextField;    // Note: does not need to be retained.
@end
```

---

```
#import "Customer.h"

@implementation Customer

@synthesize myTextField;

- (id)initUsingTextField:(NSTextField *)tf {

    if( !(self = [super init]) ) {
        return nil;
    }

    myTextField = tf;

    return self;
}

@end
```

---

*As an aside, conventionally class names in Obj-C start with uppercase letters: "Customer", not "customer".

Comment: mmmm thinking, there is not neither a way to get the keycode. It's because I've been asked to change the behaviour and actions of a searchfield with differents keys, i tried subclassing the nssearchfield and called methods from other class in the keyup but i can't change the IBOulets values or even send messages to the IBActions from the other class

Comment: @Javier: there's no reason you can't add more outlets to a custom subclass. However, sometimes subclassing a Cocoa object that has a lot of built-in behavior, like `NSSearchField`, is tricky. That's why there's so many delegate protocols in Cocoa. If you post your `keyUp:` code I'm sure someone can take a look at it.